# How browsers identify a video?

Tags: html, video

How can Search Engines identify a video?
An img tag has alt attribute:

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

A link tag has title:

```
<a href="www.apple.com" title="title of the link">this is a link</a>
```

What about video tags?
I have been searching and it does not seem to have any kind of attribute to help 
browsers to identify the video
https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Not even an embed YouTube:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zuCJYhLCN4E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen
</iframe>
```

Comment: In page *Metadata* https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/schema

Comment: Alex K. I thinks yours is the right answer. You should give that as an answer, not only a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-Page markup using the `itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject` schema:

> On-page markup is hidden descriptive data that is added to the source code of your web page. Google recommends using the schema.org, a new markup format that has been collaboratively designed and is supported by Google, Bing, and Yahoo!

See [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/schema).

<sup>(The links on that page that point to www.schema.org are broken, they should be just schema.org/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

When one retrieves the resource using HTTP there is a Content-Type header returned that defines a type of the content located behind the URL.

This header gives the client a clue on how to treat if this is an image or a video or any other type of the data. So the search engine may perform bypassing the resources described in the document and decide if they are actually the videos.

[image]

Comment: I think the point is how I can give the right information to browsers